# How do I control the number of decimal places printed in a float?

Tags: c, precision

I want to control how many digits will be printed after the decimal point when printing a float.

The function will take `n` as an input.

For example, if I have `double F = 123.456789`, and:

- If n = 2, then output `123.46`
- If n = 3, then output `123.457`
- If n = 10, then output `123.4567890000`

Comment: See `.*` in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: *Oh lovely.* OP posts, gets answer(s) and deletes profile. Good one.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
printf("%.2lf\n", F);
printf("%.3lf\n", F);
printf("%.10lf\n", F);
```

As you want to control it, you can use `*` modifier as a placeholder.

```
int n;
double F = 123.456789;
scanf("%d", &n);
printf("%.*lf\n",n, F);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int n = 2;
    double number = 123.456789;

    printf("%.*lf", n, number);  

    return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
123.46
```

Answer (score 0):

Use format specifiers. Examples:

```
%.4f    (print as a floating point with a precision of four characters after the decimal point)
%3.2f   (print as a floating point at least 3 wide and a precision of 2)
```

Please read: http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output